# Update Translation source configuration using Core Service

Tags: core-service, web8, translation-manager

I would like to update the Translation Source configuration using core service. Here is what I have done so far,

```
        var publication = TridionCoreServiceFactory.TryGet<PublicationData>(publicationId);
        TranslationJobManager manager = new TranslationJobManager("Administrator");
        PublicationConfiguration publicationConfiguration = manager.GetPublicationConfiguration(publicationId);

        var sourceTranslationID = publicationConfiguration.ClientId;
```

But, the **ClientId** seems to have read-only properties(no setter). So, is there any other options avialable to update the translation source configuration for a  publication ?

Comment: Please check core services log-in user rights. administrator rights required to change publication properties. Please try to user power shell script for update publication properties.